# C# default Write Property name

Tags: c#, properties

Is there any way to fast override the "value" name for a new variable that is placed in the set block in C#?

```cs
class Foo {
    string name = "guy";
    public string Name {
        get {
            return name;
        }
        set {
            if (value != "foo") {
                name = value;
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("sorry I already took that one!");
            }
        }
    }
```

For example in swift I could write it this way:

```cs
var Name: String {
    get {
        return name;
    }
    set (newName) {
        if (newName == "Foo") {
            print("sorry I already took that one!")
        } else {
            name = newName;
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can easily solve it by assignment at the beginning of the block but the approach with naming the value in parenthesis just after the keyword is very clear to me so just wanted to ask is there another solution.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the two codes you posted aside from the inverse `if`... What am I missing? What do you mean by *"fast override the "value""*?

Comment: I read this few times but still didn't get what's the question.

Comment: @Ron I believe he is looking for a way to access the value in the setter using a variable name. As if he had done `string newName = value` at the beginning of the setter. In other words, type `newName` instead of `value`, without creating a local variable.

Comment: @St.Pat Possibly, but I'm not sure `value` is any less clear, `value` is always the incoming value in the setter, so still not sure what the difference is other than a different variable name.

Comment: @St.Pat yes that's exactly what I'm asking for. Sorry was hard for me to set up this question properly

Comment: Can I check: the issue here is just the name `value` - you'd prefer `newName`? if so... no, not really, except for `var newName = value;` - which seems unnecessary

Comment: @OfftheCode In that case, no, other than creating a new local variable, there is no way to override `value`.

Comment: @RonBeyer I know that value is clear but I'm just used to overriding it for the case of the block for more precise meaning.

Comment: You are welcome to do `var newName = value;` at the top, the compiler will optimize it out in release code so it doesn't do anything performance wise.

Comment: @RonBeyer ok thank You very much, just was curious.

Comment: No, you can´t alias `value` without declaring a variable. In fact that doesn´t work for *any* statement, you allways need a variable. I don´t see what´s the problem on declaring one, anyway.

Comment: @MarcGravell no issue just thing I'm used to after working with Swift, it was just clear for me to type the exact name of thing that's coming from input like newDate or smt like that rather than just value. I know it might sound silly but I worked like that before maybe it's bad practice to be honest I'm not sure.

Comment: @HimBromBeere no problem with declaring just looking for any "built in version" to achieve it

Comment: @OfftheCode yeah, I understand the motivation; on the other hand, though: `value` is a contextual keyword in C#, so it shows up with syntax highlighting in the IDE (blue, usually), plus everyone knows what `value` is in a setter :)

Comment: Anyways thank You all guys for answering this weird question!

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah now I'm understanding that it might be even better because everyone knows about the "new incoming value" name thanks for your time once again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, no. It is a language feature that `value` is the contextual keyword that always represents the incoming value in a `set` accessor (and in custom event accessors).

You can fake it:

```
var newName = value;
```

but... you get better syntax highlighting with `value` than `newName`, and any C# reader automatically knows what `value` represents in that context.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!